# WatchOS - best way to make int visible to all wkinterfacecontroller

Tags: int, parameter-passing, watchkit

In wkinterfacecontroller 1 i defined two int values named: base[8][8] and player[8][8]. With an for Loop i generate My values for both.
Now i want to geht Access to them in wkinterfacecontroller 2 and 3.

But i dont really know how. Save every int in nsuserdefaults and load in the other Controllers is a Little bit weird...

Comment: Do your other view controllers need to modify those properties?

Comment: Yes. Controller 2 and 3 have to modify them and controller 1 show them to the user

Answer (score 1):

Create a **singleton model** that holds your data. Reference this class from all of your views that need this data. With the code below you can reference the 'model' by calling `[Model sharedModel]`. Access a variable: `[Model sharedModel].myVariableName`.

```
// Model.m
// This method will only create one instance of Model no matter how many times it's called. 
// Import its header and use this method to get its reference
+ (instancetype)sharedModel
{
    static Model *sharedModel;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedModel = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
    });
    return sharedModel;
}

// Raise exception to make sure you don't create more than one object of the Model class
- (instancetype)init {
    [NSException raise:@"Singleton"
                format:@"Use +[Model sharedModel]"];
    return nil;
}

// Private init method
- (instancetype)initPrivate
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // Set properties
    } 
    return self;
}
```